# Difference between urbanairship and parse and push for push notification in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification

Hi i am working  for the push notification in current project in ios, but i dont know about Urbanairship or Parse, push, and client says to me that use one of them which is free and better for this purpose, so please tell me which one is better for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urban Airship is doing away with free notifications. I work for [XtremePush](http://www.xtremepush.com) who do push notifications to the same standard as Urban Airship and have a free tier if you want to check that out.